# Why Bitwise AND operation not working for Value>=8?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bitwise-and

This program is to check whether a given number is a power of 2. This code works properly till n=7 and it gives irrelevant output for input n<=8.

Input n = 4;
Output : 0 ;
Expected output : 0

Input : n = 8;
Output: 104;
Expected output : 0

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = input.nextInt();
    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    String s2 = Integer.toBinaryString(n-1);
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    Integer j = Integer.parseInt(s2);
    System.out.println(i&j);
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting the integer via a string, back to an integer again ?
The number will be a power of two, if only one bit in the number (after converting to binary) is set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calls of `toBinaryString` and `parseInt` you distort the number by converting it to binary, and then interpreting the binary as decimal. Just skip this:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(n&(n-1));
    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessary conversion from **int** to **string** and then **Integer**. You can direct perform ***bitwise*** and operation between ***int***. See the following code to understand the operation as well as the binary conversion -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter n : ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number 1 : "+n);
        int n2= n-1;
        System.out.println("Number 2: "+n2);
        System.out.println("------Just to see the coressponding binary value-----------");
        String binaryNumber1 = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
        System.out.println("Binary Number 1 : "+binaryNumber1);
        String binaryNumber2 = Integer.toBinaryString(n2);
        System.out.println("Binary Number 1 : "+binaryNumber2);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Bitwise AND operation :  "+(n & n2));   //  actual AND operation perform here
        
       
        input.close();

    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter n : 13
---------------------
Number 1 : 13
Number 2: 12
------Just to see the coressponding binary value-----------
Binary Number 1 : 1101
Binary Number 2 : 1100
-----------------------------------------------------------
Bitwise AND operation :  12
```